# Changing the value of work items tags after an Azure DevOps build

Tags: powershell, tags, azure-devops, pipeline

I am creating the CI for my company and we are using Azure Devops for it. I would like to add a PowerShell script at the end of my pipeline that tags all the related parent work items with the tag "ReadyToTest" once the build has completed. Has anyone ever done anything like this or similar as i am stumped.

//pseudo code

- List all work items related to build
- Find parents of work items
- Foreach parent workitem tag Ready to tag

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

You could check the following apis to get related information:

1. [Builds - Get Build Work Items Refs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/get%20build%20work%20items%20refs?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0): Gets the work items associated with a build.

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds/{buildId}/workitems?api-version=5.0`

2. [Work Items - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0): Returns a list of work items to find the parent work items.

`GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems?ids={ids}&api-version=5.0`

3. [Work Items - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0#update_a_field): Updates a single work item to change the tag.

`PATCH https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workitems/{id}?api-version=5.0`

Comment: Hey thanks for this i will give it a try soon and let you know if it works!! thanks again. Can you place this into the powershell script? sorry noob at powershell :P

Comment: You could refer to the following link to use DevOps REST API with powershell: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/using-vsts-api-with-powershell-to-scaffold-team-projects/